# Conditional validation for fields based on select option - yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

So while learning, forms i found this package - [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) for validating. But i am getting a problem

So i will explain the problem statement and what i have tried so far.

So the use case is i have a select field, which has two options, Resident and Non-Resident, so based on the selection i have different fields which i render

- **Resident** : first_name, last_name
- **Non-Resident**: passport_number, country, state

So here what i thought of splitting the schema and based on the selection i want to add the additional fields schema for the validation.

```
const required = () => "Field is required";

const resident_schema = object({
  first_name: string().required(required).nullable(),
  last_name: string().required(required).nullable(),
});

const non_resident_schema = object({
  passport_number: string().required(required).nullable(),
  country: object().required(required).nullable(),
  state: object().required(required).nullable(),
});

const schemaBasedCitizen = {
  RESIDENT: resident_schema,
  NON-RESIDENT: non_resident_schema,
};

export const validationSchema = object().shape({
  citizen: object().required(required).nullable(),
  { ...object().when("citizen", {
    is: (value) => !!schemaBasedCitizen[value.toUpperCase()],
    then: (value) => schemaBasedCitizen[value.toUpperCase()],
  }) },
});
```

And my html consist of

```
<select>
 <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
 <option value='resident'>Resident</option>
 <option value='non-resident'>Non-Resident</option>
</select>
```

I am not able to spread, since key requires, So is there a way to achieve this.

**Update**

Schema when value is resident in select field

```
export const validationSchema = object().shape({
      citizen: object().required(required).nullable(),
      first_name: string().required(required).nullable(),
      last_name: string().required(required).nullable(),
    });
```

Schema when value is non-resident in select field

```
export const validationSchema = object().shape({
      citizen: object().required(required).nullable(),
      passport_number: string().required(required).nullable(),
      country: object().required(required).nullable(),
      state: object().required(required).nullable(),
    });
```

Basically the validation is dynamic based on the value on citizen select field.

Comment: What's the name of your select field? EDIT: Actually, can you show the desired **output** from both schemas?

Comment: <select name=''citizen"> @Adam

Comment: So in jsx, i show only the fields according to the selection. Sure will update the question

Comment: @Adam I have updated as requested, Kindly check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup has this thing that it can only reference **sibling** fields (or context) using `when`.

Your `citizen` field is NOT a sibling of the rest of the object and can't be used to conditionally change the object schema, it's a **child** of the object, so you can't reference it as a sibling field via `when`.

One way to accomplish what you want could be to use a [lazy](https://github.com/jquense/yup#yuplazyvalue-any--schema-lazy) schema:

```js
import { lazy } from 'yup';

const residentSchema = ...
const nonResidentSchema = ...

export const validationSchema = lazy(({citizen}) => citizen === 'resident' ? residentSchema : nonResidentSchema);
```

Comment: Okay, but one doubt, tried this but every time its overwriting. So the use case i selected resident, now i clicked on the first name field and didn't entered anything and clicked on last name field, now the error message shows, but when i click on the last name field the first name error is not persisting its overwriting. How can i solve this one. So at a time only one error message shows even though two fields have empty value

Comment: @JohnThomas - that sounds like a completely different issue (deserving of a different question). It depends on the framework you're using to manage your form data/display your error messages.

Comment: @ Adam  Sure i will add a codesandbox for the issue to reproduce and will add here. Kindly guide me on the same.

Comment: @ Adam this is the codesandbox, where i tried, but i think some re rendering is happening. I am not understanding where the issue is occurring. Let me know what i am doing wrong over here, and how can i solve the issue. Values also getting reset https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-dust-lnyqu

Comment: @JohnThomas - please open another question.

Comment: @ Adam sure. will open and share here

Comment: @ Adam, can you check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64139855/form-validation-with-conditional-fields-using-yup

Comment: @ Adam where you able to run it